# A metal block in a tub of frictionless ball bearings

Tags: classical-mechanics

If you place a metal block in a tub of small frictionless ball bearings of the same metal, would it stay on top or sink?..

Answer (score 1):

The block will have higher density because of the air gaps between the steel balls so it should sink to the bottom.

Comment: that was my thought also but wasn't sure if it's a trick question :]